# Finding lowest value in a series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
   a   b   c
a  12  23  3
b  5   31  41
c  14  4   20
```

and I want to find the lowest value in column 'a' which would be `df['a']['b'] = 5`

but I can't find a one-line command to retrieve it, how do I get the lowest value in column a without referencing the row name?

Comment: by row name you mean index? are you looking for [min](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html)?

Comment: @grimrol123 if you just want to get the minimum value for series a , use **df['a'].min()**

Comment: following the @Snehil it should work if you are searching the minimum in the first line, otherwise, if you want the global you can do min([ df[i].min() for i in ["a","b", "c"]])

Comment: @Snehil what if you want to find the minimum value for column a excluding index a, in the case of df['a']['a'] being the lowest value in column 'a'?

Comment: @ grimrol123 , if  you want to drop an index named **a** from a **series** named **a**  and then find the minimum , you could do this **df.drop(['indexes_to_be_dropped'])['series_name'].min()**   , for the example you asked, it would be **df.drop(['a'])['a'].min()**

Comment: @Snehil Thank you very much. I just have one more question if you can spare the time, how would I retrieve said index name with the lowest value?

Comment: @grimrol123 you can use **df['series_name'].idxmin()** , or in this question **df['a'].idxmin()** to find that,  as one of the answers already mentions it.

Comment: @Snehil Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
    a   b   c
d
a  12  23   3
b   5  31  41
c  14   4  20

In [20]: df.a.min()
Out[20]: 5

In [21]: df.b.min()
Out[21]: 4

In [22]: df.c.min()
Out[22]: 3

In [23]: df.min()
Out[23]:
a    5
b    4
c    3
dtype: int64

In [24]: df.min()['b']
Out[24]: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.min()["a"]
```

would find the lowest value in column A (5, in this case).

```
df.idxmin()["a"]
```

finds the label of the minimum ('b', in this case).